# Is TIKZ sending ambiguous PDF instructions that only TEXstudio understands well?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, texshop, distributions, texnicle

TEXstudio is the only MAC software (although not originally designed for MAC) that has a PDF viewer that renders perfectly well dashed and hatched lines drawn with tikz. What does TEXstudio do that all the other softwares (TEXshop, TEXnicle, Preview, Acrobat Reader) don't do ? Does TEXstudio bring with it the perfect PDF encoding ? Is tikz sending ambiguous PDF instructions ?

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    % code taken from Arberto Sartori:  http://www.albertosartori.it/latexother.php
    \makeatletter
    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\LineSpace,\LineWidth]{my north east lines}
        {\pgfqpoint{-\LineWidth}{-\LineWidth}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}
        {\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}%
        {
            \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
            \pgfsetlinewidth{\LineWidth}
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\LineWidth}{-\LineWidth}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        }
    \makeatother

    \newdimen\LineSpace
    \newdimen\PointSize
    \newdimen\LineWidth
    \tikzset{
        line space/.code={\LineSpace=#1},
        line space=3pt
    }
    \tikzset{
        point size/.code={\PointSize=#1},
        point size=.5pt
    }
    \tikzset{
        pattern line width/.code={\LineWidth=#1},
        pattern line width=.4pt
    }


    \tcbset{dash/.style={%
    enhanced,%
    frame style={pattern=my north east lines,pattern color=blue!80!white,
    line space=9pt,pattern line width=3pt,dashed},%
    leftrule=5mm,rightrule=5mm,toprule=5mm,bottomrule=0.3mm}} %

    \tcbset{hatch/.style={%
    enhanced,%
    frame style={pattern=my north east lines,pattern color=red!80!white,
    line space=9pt,pattern line width=3pt},%
    leftrule=5mm,rightrule=5mm,toprule=5mm,bottomrule=0.3mm}} %

    \begin{document}


    \begin{tcolorbox}[dash]
    North east DASHED lines
    \end{tcolorbox}


    \begin{tcolorbox}[hatch]
    North east HATCHED lines
    \end{tcolorbox}


    \end{document}
```

Perfect PDF result viewed (zoom-independent) in TEXStudio:
[image]

TEXshop / failure dash + hatch:
[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMQ4D.png)

TEXshop / zoom on / failure dash, but OK hatch:
[image]

TEXnicle / failure dash + hatch:
[image]

TEXnicle / zoom-on / failure dash + hatch:
[image]

Preview (OS 10.10) / same result as TEXnicle / failure dash + hatch:
[image]

Preview (OS 10.10) / zoom on / same result as TEXnicle / failure dash + hatch:
[image]

Acrobat Reader 11.0.09/ failure dash, but hatch OK
[image]

Acrobat Reader 11.0.09 / zoom on / failure dash, but hatch OK
[image]

Comment: Looks perfect with `evince`, I mean identical to TEXstudio.

Comment: If you change the order `hatch `before `dash` all is red. Looks like in TeXStudio with TeXworks viewer. Doesn't work with SumatraPDF and PDFX-change viewer.

Comment: Acrobat should be fine from your screenshot. Play with the zoom level.

Comment: Sorry:"red" and "blue" were another issue, not the main one for that question / I updated my screen shots and question accordingly.

Comment: I blame the pattern code

Comment: Percusse, could you be more precise ?

Comment: I doubt it is the reason for the different renderings but `\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}` is never going to work as `\pgfqpoint` does not do any calculations.

Comment: Why the code ? Even if you use the built-in tikz pattern=north east lines, you get the same results with the different viewers for MAC. And, if the problem were the code, why would TEXstudio be the only one to guess it right ?

Comment: I don't have any problems with sumatra and Acroread with regular patterns. It has been always an issue with other viewers that is asked elsewhere on this site. I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendering is performed by the PDF rendering engine/library used by the program. For example:

- TeXstudio uses [poppler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler).
- SumatraPDF uses [MuPDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MuPDF).
- Adobe uses its own proprietary engine.
- OSX has its own PDF engine (not an expert here but I assume Preview uses the builtin PDF capabilities of [Quartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_%28graphics_layer%29))

I don't know the details of the PDF specification here. Either it's ambigous or not all engines implement it strictly. Either way, the different engines interpret your example differently.

Comment: Similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217879/tikz-pattern-north-west-lines-dashed