# tikz pattern north west lines dashed

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello I am trying to create a figure with tikz.  Im using patterns to define a few different regions.
zone 0 is gray
zone 1 is north east lines
z2 is north west lines

For some reason the diagonal patterns are coming out dashed.  And Im not sure why.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Below is my code and a screen shot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5]
    %\tkzAxeXY
    %zone 2 (rectangle, negative)
    \fill[pattern=north west lines] (0,5) rectangle (5.5,0);
    %circle mask
    \fill[white] (4,1.5) circle (1.35);
    %zone 1
    \node[minimum width=2.7cm,
    circle,inner sep=0pt,fill opacity=1,
    line width=2.5mm,pattern=north east lines,opacity=1] at (4,1.5){};
    %zone 0 (positive)
    \node[minimum width=2cm,
    circle,inner sep=0pt,fill opacity=1,
    line width=2.5mm,draw=gray,opacity=1] at (4,1.5){};
    %wall (dashed line)
    \node[minimum width=2cm,
    circle,inner sep=0pt,fill opacity=0,
    line width=.5mm,dashed,draw=black,opacity=1] at (4,1.5){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bad Lines]

Comment: Welcome to TexSE! I wonder what version of TikZ you are using?  On my plain TexLive 2014 system (Mac OSX) the diagonal lines come out solid.

Comment: Is there a way to check? I am using MacTex 2014 and using latexmk to build

Comment: add `\listfiles` say before `\begin{document}`, you will get list of files with version in the log.

Comment: tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)

Comment: I think this is a renderer-side problem. I tried exporting PDF to PNG and the latter looks good. (By the way, so are they dashed in tikz manual.)

Comment: I don't have problem (lines are solid) when compiling your code with the same TikZ version and PDF/Lua/Xe/LaTex. This is probably a viewer problem. Have you checked with another viewer?

Comment: Similar question to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212551/is-tikz-sending-ambiguous-pdf-instructions-that-only-texstudio-understands-well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is a renderer-side problem. For the code at the end, the left one is the screenshot and the right one is the exported PNG.

[image]
[image]

Here are some code/comment from `pgfcorepatterns.code.tex`;

```
% Creates a new colored pattern
%
% [#1] = optional list of variables.
% #2   = pattern name
% #3   = lower left of bounding box
% #4   = upper right of bounding box
% #5   = step vector
% #6   = pattern code
%
% Description:
%
% Declares a new colored pattern. Such patterns have a one or more
% fixed inherent colors. See the pdf-manual for more details on
% uncolored patterns.
%
% The parameters have the same effect as for uncolored patterns.
```

and code from `pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex`.

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{north east lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{4pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.1pt}{3.1pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
```

So I think this is what happened

[image]

and what I did

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly{south west lines}{\pgfqpoint{-0pt}{-0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}{
        \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.8pt}{-.2pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.2pt}{.2pt}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.2pt}{2.8pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.2pt}{3.2pt}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[pattern=north east lines](0,1)rectangle(1,0);
        \fill[pattern=south west lines](0,1)rectangle(-1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.4cm]
        \begin{scope}[opacity=.25]
            \draw[thin](1,2)rectangle(2,1)(1.5,1)node[below]{de facto bounding box};
            \draw[thin](0,3)rectangle(3,0)(1.5,0)node[below]{tessellating box};
            \draw[thin](-1,4)rectangle(4,-1)(1.5,-1)node[below]{bounding box};
            \draw[opacity=0](-1,4)rectangle(4,-1);
            \draw(0,0)--(3.1,3.1);
        \end{scope}
        \clip(1,2)rectangle(2,1);
        \draw(0,0)--(3,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.4cm]
        \begin{scope}[opacity=.25]
            \draw[thin](0,3)rectangle(3,0)(1.5,0)node[below]{bounding box = tessellating box};
            \draw(0,0)--(3,3)(-.2,2.8)--(.2,3.2)(2.8,-.2)--(3.2,.2);
        \end{scope}
        \clip(0,3)rectangle(3,0);
        \draw(0,0)--(3,3)(-.2,2.8)--(.2,3.2)(2.8,-.2)--(3.2,.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## south east version

For your convenience, here is a south east version

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{south east lines}{\pgfqpoint{-0pt}{-0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{3pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.2pt}{-.2pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.2pt}{.2pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{3.2pt}{2.8pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.8pt}{3.2pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}}
```

Comment: When you say "the screen shot", what viewer are you using ? When you say "exported PNG", how you export it ?

Comment: @Kpym I am using Preview on OS X. The screenshot is what I saw when I opened the PDF file. And then from menubar `File`->`Export...`-> `PNG`

Comment: This looks like an OS X previewer problam, and not a TikZ one for me. You can check your PDF in another viewer (Acrobat/Chrome/...) .

Comment: @Kpym I believe it is. On Chrome it looks all right. By the way, it looks good in Finder's quick view.

Comment: Similar question to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212551/is-tikz-sending-ambiguous-pdf-instructions-that-only-texstudio-understands-well

Comment: Can you do one for south east please?

Comment: @MatthewTang Is this still a problem? On which machine/PDF reader?

Comment: @Symbol 1, on the ShareLatex website. I'm playing around with your code to make the direction north west as we speak.

Comment: Thanks. I also happen to have problems with the grid patterns. Please see https://ibb.co/ftWBka

Comment: @MatthewTang You may either ask a followup question; or search `pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex` for the definition of patterns and play with them.

Comment: I still have that problem. PGF version 3.0.1, Miktex, in Adobe Reader, Firefox and Poppler (TexStudio). Microsoft Edge seems to be the only exception.

Comment: @jaytar You are saying that you have problems with or without my patch? I might not be able to help in either case but maybe ask a new question?

Comment: Without that patch. Your patch is fine, but you asked Matthew Tang if the problem persists, and I wanted to give an update.