# How to shade areas inside a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to shade specific areas of a graph using the following code

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)--(6,0);
\draw(0,0)--(0,3);
\draw [blue] (.1,.3) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] +(0.:.2cm)  to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] +(35:3.cm)  to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] +(-35:3.cm)  to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] +(0.:.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

to produce the following shades

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a system handy right now. Have you taken a look at the document called "tikz-minimal"? It's part of the tikz doc. Do you know how to find the doc files in your TeX tree?

Comment: I am using MiktexPortable; and I did not find the tikz-minimal doc in its folder.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf contains the sought for document. For another time, thanks to marmot. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would have drawn your (Gaussian) function with pgfplots, things would be even more straightforward. However, as you are not, there is no need to load the pgfplots package, and one can do things with Ti*k*Z only.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)--(6,0);
\draw(0,0)--(0,3);
\draw[blue] (.1,.3) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] +(0.:.2cm)  to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] +(35:3.cm)  to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] +(-35:3.cm)  to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] +(0.:.2cm);
\path[clip] (.1,-1)-- (.1,.3) to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] +(0.:.2cm)  to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] +(35:3.cm)  to [out=0,in=180, looseness=.68] +(-35:3.cm)  to [out=0,in=180, looseness=1.] +(0.:.2cm)
 -- (5.4,-1) -- cycle;
\only<1>{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaX}{0.6}
\filldraw[pattern=north east lines] (0.1,0) rectangle (2.75-\DeltaX,2.1) (2.75+\DeltaX,2.1) rectangle (5.4,0);
\draw (2.75-\DeltaX,0.1) -- (2.75-\DeltaX,-0.1) node[below] {-1}
 (2.75+\DeltaX,0.1) -- (2.75+\DeltaX,-0.1) node[below] {+1};
\draw (2.75,2.1)-- (2.75,-0.1) node[below]{0};
}
\only<2>{
\filldraw[pattern=north east lines] (1.25,0) rectangle (2.75,2.1);
\draw (1.25,-0.1) node[below] {14000}  -- (1.25,0.88) -- (2.75,0.88);
\draw (2.75,-0.1) node[below] {16000}  -- (2.75,0.88+0.56) -- (1.25,0.88+0.56);
}
\only<3>{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaX}{1}
\filldraw[pattern=north east lines] (0,0) rectangle (2.75+\DeltaX,2.1);
\draw (2.75+\DeltaX,0) -- (2.75+\DeltaX,1.8) -- (1,1.8);
\draw (2.75,2.1)-- (2.75,0);
}
\only<4>{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaX}{0.6}
\fill[pattern=north east lines] (2.75-0.5*\DeltaX,0) rectangle (2.75+\DeltaX,2.1);
\draw (2.75-0.5*\DeltaX,2.1) -- (2.75-0.5*\DeltaX,-0.1) node[below left] {-0.5}
 (2.75+\DeltaX,2.1) -- (2.75+\DeltaX,-0.1) node[below right] {+1};
\draw (2.75,2.1)-- (2.75,-0.1) node[below]{0};
\draw (2.75-0.5*\DeltaX,1.5) -- (2.75+\DeltaX,1.5);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to ask for one more addition please; how to make the pattern lines coloured or dashed

Comment: @Hany You can set the `pattern color`  e.g. with `\fill[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red]` . For the dashed version, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219808/121799).