# TikZ - Clipping the squares ring

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to create the following picture but I have not succeeded.

[image]

I just made it like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,patterns,knots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document} 
\pagecolor{LightSkyBlue1!30}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line cap=rounded]
\coordinate[label=left:] (A) at (0,2);
\coordinate[label=right:] (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=left:] (O) at (0,1);
\fill[Cyan4] (-.175,-.175) rectangle (9.175,2.175);
\begin{knot}[clip width=2,clip radius=0cm]
    \strand[white,line width=0.1cm,double=Cyan4,double distance=.15cm,even odd rule] (-.175,-.175)--(1,1)--(-.175,2.175)
    (1,0)--(2,1)--(1,2)--(0,1)--cycle
    (2,0)--(3,1)--(2,2)--(1,1)--cycle
    (3,0)--(4,1)--(3,2)--(2,1)--cycle
    (4,0)--(5,1)--(4,2)--(3,1)--cycle
    (5,0)--(6,1)--(5,2)--(4,1)--cycle
    (6,0)--(7,1)--(6,2)--(5,1)--cycle
    (7,0)--(8,1)--(7,2)--(6,1)--cycle
    (8,0)--(9,1)--(8,2)--(7,1)--cycle
    (9.175,2.175)--(8,1)--(9.175,-.175);
\end{knot}
\draw[ultra thick,Cyan4] (-.2,-.2) rectangle (9.2,2.2);
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\path[pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=Cyan4] 
(-.175,-.175) rectangle (9.175,2.175)
(-.5,-.5) rectangle (9.5,2.5) ;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How to create the original image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very quick eyeballing solution

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[postaction=fill] (0,-2) rectangle (8,2);
\foreach\x in{1.5,0,-1.5}{\foreach\y in{-4,...,4}{\draw[white,thick](0,\x+ 0.1*\y)--++(8,0);}}
\foreach \x in {0,...,8}{
  \node[diamond,minimum size=1.5cm] (n-\x) at (\x, 0) {};
  \draw[draw=white,double=black, double distance between line centers=2mm,line width=1mm] 
  ([shift={(-135:3mm)}]n-\x.east)--(n-\x.east)--(n-\x.north)--([shift={(45:5mm)}]n-\x.west)
  ([shift={(-135:5mm)}]n-\x.east)--(n-\x.south)--(n-\x.west)--([shift={(45:2.2mm)}]n-\x.west);
  \draw[thick] ([yshift=0.21cm]n-\x.north) -- ([yshift=-0.21cm]n-\x.south);
}
\draw[thick](0,0)--++(8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Maybe more complete option but with some tricky elements, and some patterns issues like diferent rendering in some pdf viewers..., but you can modify to obtain some good result in your document.

RESULT: TikzEdt viewer
[image]

RESULT: Firefox viewer ...`{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]`
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,backgrounds}
%Create a new patern maybe needs tune for firefox and adobe reader from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219808/154390
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{mypatt}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3.4pt}{3.4pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3.4pt}{3.4pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.8pt}
  %Principal line
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{0pt}}
  %Complement line north east
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-1.5pt}{2.4pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.5pt}{2.4pt}}
  %Complement line south west
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-1.5pt}{-2.4pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.5pt}{-2.4pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{mypatt2}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3.4pt}{3.4pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3.4pt}{3.4pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.5pt}
  %Principal line
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.5pt}{0pt}}
   %Complement line north east
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{1.7pt}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.5pt}{1.7pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\begin{document} 
\pagecolor{LightSkyBlue1!30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\def\DECOR(#1)[#2]#3#4{% Draw the decoration pattern
%#1:position #2:rotation #3:color #4: ID
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}, rotate=#2]
    \draw[line width=1pt,color=#3] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle ++ (1,1);
    \fill[pattern=mypatt, pattern color=white](0,0)++(-0.5,-0.5)
        --++(1,0)--++(0,0.5)--++(-0.5,-0.5)--++(-0.5,0.5) -- cycle;
    \fill[pattern=mypatt2, pattern color=white](0,0)++(-0.5,0.5)
        rectangle ++(1,0.5);
    \draw[line width=1pt, fill=white,draw=#3](0,0)++(0,-0.5)
        --++(-0.5,0)--++(1,1)--++(0,-0.5) -- cycle;
    \draw[line width=1pt, fill=#3,draw=#3](0,0)++(-2/6,-0.5)
        --++(1/6,0)--++(0.5+1/6,0.5+1/6)--++(0,1/6) -- cycle;
    \draw[line width=1pt, fill=white,draw=Cyan4](0,0)++(0,-0.5)
        --++(0.5,0)--++(-1,1)--++(0,-0.5) -- cycle;
    \draw[line width=1pt, fill=#3,color=#3](0,0)++(2/6,-0.5)
        --++(-1/6,0)--++(-0.5-1/6,0.5+1/6)--++(0,1/6) -- cycle;
    \coordinate (C #4) at (-0.5,1);
\end{scope}
}

\foreach \n in {1,2,...,7}{% Draw nine blocks
    \DECOR(\n,0.5)[0]{Cyan4}{u\n}
    \DECOR(\n,-0.5)[180]{Cyan4}{d\n}
}
\begin{scope}[on background layer] %  Nice trick from Zarko's answer.
  \draw[line width=1pt, fill=Cyan4,draw=Cyan4] (C u1) rectangle (C d7); 
  \path[pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=Cyan4] (C u1)++(-0.5,0.5) rectangle ++(8,-4);  
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```