# tree phase induction machine

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw an diagram of an induction machine like this:
[Cross-section of an electric machine circuit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448737/cross-section-of-an-electric-machine-circuit)

Would it be possible to convert this drawing to a tree-phase machine?
I tried but I couldn't do much...

Thanks!

Comment: Please describe your question more clearly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please show us, what you try so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours I was able to do something similar to what I wanted in the beginning.
Thanks for the help. I relied on the example provided in the following link: [Cross-section of an electric machine circuit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448737/cross-section-of-an-electric-machine-circuit)

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \usepackage[outline]{contour}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,patterns,backgrounds}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[inset=0,length=5pt]}]
        % Definitions
        \def\rotationAngle{35}
        \def\rotorRadius{1.4}
        \def\statorRadius{2}

        \def\Current[#1][#2](#3)(#4)#5#6[#7]{%1: Angle 2: radious 3:type 4:ID 5:color 6:Label text 7:polar text position.
            \draw (#1:#2)++(#7:0.5) node {\contour{white}{#6}};
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1:#2)}, rotate=#1-90,transform shape]
                \node[inner sep=0,minimum size=13pt](I#4) at (0,0){};
                \ifnum#3=0 \draw[#5,thick](45:5pt)--(-135:5pt) (-45:5pt)--(135:5pt) (0,0) circle (5pt); \fi
                \ifnum#3=1 \draw[#5,thick](0,0) circle (5pt);\fill[#5](0,0) circle (2pt); \fi       
            \end{scope}
        }

        %Drawing Stator
        \Current[0][\statorRadius](1)(1){blue}{$i_{as}$}[-90]
        \Current[60][\statorRadius](0)(2){green}{$i_{cs}$}[-30]
        \Current[120][\statorRadius](1)(3){red}{$i_{bs}$}[30]
        \Current[180][\statorRadius](0)(4){blue}{$i_{as}$}[90]
        \Current[240][\statorRadius](1)(5){green}{$i_{cs}$}[150]
        \Current[300][\statorRadius](0)(6){red}{$i_{bs}$}[210]

        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw[thick, even odd rule, fill=black, fill opacity=0.2]
            let \p1 = (I1.south west),
                \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
                \n2 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)}
            in  (\n2:\n1) 
                    arc (\n2:60-\n2:\n1)--(I2.north east)--(I2.north west)--(I2.south west) 
                    arc (60+\n2:120-\n2:\n1)--(I3.north east)--(I3.north west)--(I3.south west)
                    arc (120+\n2:180-\n2:\n1)--(I4.north east)--(I4.north west)--(I4.south west)
                    arc (180+\n2:240-\n2:\n1)--(I5.north east)--(I5.north west)--(I5.south west)
                    arc (240+\n2:300-\n2:\n1)--(I6.north east)--(I6.north west)--(I6.south west)
                    arc (300+\n2:360-\n2:\n1)--(I1.north east)--(I1.north west)--(I1.south west)
            (0,0) circle (3);
        \draw[->, thick](I1.north)-- ++(0:1.5) node[anchor=180]{$as$};
        \draw[->, thick](I3.north)-- ++(120:1.5) node[anchor=300]{$bs$};
        \draw[->, thick](I5.north)-- ++(240:1.5) node[anchor=60]{$cs$};
        \draw[thick]
            (I1.south)--(I4.south)
            (I2.south)--(I5.south)
            (I3.south)--(I6.south)
            (I2.north)-- ++(60:1)
            (I4.north)-- ++(180:1)
            (I6.north)-- ++(300:1);
        \end{scope}

        %Drawing Rotor
        \contourlength{0pt}
        \begin{scope}[rotate=\rotationAngle]
        \Current[0][\rotorRadius](1)(7){blue}{$i_{ar}$}[-100]
        \Current[60][\rotorRadius](0)(8){green}{$i_{cr}$}[-40]
        \Current[120][\rotorRadius](1)(9){red}{$i_{br}$}[20]
        \Current[180][\rotorRadius](0)(10){blue}{$i_{ar}$}[80]
        \Current[240][\rotorRadius](1)(11){green}{$i_{cr}$}[140]
        \Current[300][\rotorRadius](0)(12){red}{$i_{br}$}[200]

            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
                \draw[thick, fill=black, fill opacity=0.2]
                    let \p1 = (I7.north west),
                        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
                        \n2 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)}
                    in  (\n2:\n1)
                            arc (\n2:60-\n2:\n1)--(I8.south east)--(I8.south west)--(I8.north west) 
                            arc (60+\n2:120-\n2:\n1)--(I9.south east)--(I9.south west)--(I9.north west)
                            arc (120+\n2:180-\n2:\n1)--(I10.south east)--(I10.south west)--(I10.north west)
                            arc (180+\n2:240-\n2:\n1)--(I11.south east)--(I11.south west)--(I11.north west)
                            arc (240+\n2:300-\n2:\n1)--(I12.south east)--(I12.south west)--(I12.north west)
                            arc (300+\n2:360-\n2:\n1)--(I7.south east)--(I7.south west)--(I7.north west);
                \draw[->, thick, shorten >=10pt](I7.north)-- ++(0:2.4) node{$ar$};
                \draw[->, thick, shorten >=10pt](I9.north)-- ++(120:2.4) node{$br$};
                \draw[->, thick, shorten >=10pt](I11.north)-- ++(240:2.4) node{$cr$};
                \draw[thick]
                    (I7.south)--(I10.south)
                    (I8.south)--(I11.south)
                    (I9.south)--(I12.south)
                    (I8.north)-- ++(60:1.6)
                    (I10.north)-- ++(180:1.6)
                    (I12.north)-- ++(300:1.6);
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
        \draw[->,thick] (0:0.7) arc (0:\rotationAngle:0.7) node[pos=0.5, anchor=west] {$\theta_{r}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is to give you a start. The picture is a partial reproduction of a picture [found here](https://www.elprocus.com/multiphase-induction-motor/). The IMHO only somewhat subtle point is the clip at the beginning because one has to dial an appropriate orientation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,very thick,sc/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5pt}]
 \begin{scope}
  \clip (4,0) arc(0:-360:4) (0,0) circle[radius=5cm];
  \fill[gray!50,even odd rule] circle[radius=5cm] circle[radius=4cm] 
   foreach \X in {1,...,6} {(\X*60:4) circle[radius=0.5cm]};
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {A,B,C,A,B,C} { 
 \path(180-60*\Y:4) node[circle,draw] (n\Y) {\X};
 }
 \foreach \Y in {0,...,4}
 {\draw[dashed,-{Stealth[bend]}] (180-72*\Y-5:3)
    arc(180-72*\Y-5:180-72*\Y-67:3);}
 \fill[gray!70] circle[radius=1.8cm];   
 \foreach \X in {1,...,20}
 {\draw (\X*18:2) circle[radius=0.12cm];}
 \draw (n1) -- (120:5.8) coordinate (aux) -- (-6.7,0|-aux)  node[sc,left] (c1){};
 \draw (n3) -- (0:5.8) |- ([yshift=8mm]c1.east)  node[sc,left] (c3){};
 \draw (n5) -- (-120:5.8) -| ([yshift=-8mm,xshift=5mm]c1.east)  
 -- ++(-0.5,0)node[sc,left] (c5){};
 \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=2pt}] (c3.north west) -- (c5.south west)
  node[midway,left=3pt,align=right]{3 Phase\\ input};
 \draw (n0) -| (-5.8,-5.8) node[sc,fill] {} -- ++ (-1,0)
  node[left,sc,label=left:Common] (Common){};
 \draw (n4) -- (-60:5.6) coordinate(aux) -- (aux|-Common) node[sc,fill]{};
 \draw (n2) -- (60:5.6) coordinate(aux) -- (aux-|6,0) |- (Common);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I like the way you designed the black lines with black dots and arrows!

Comment: @manooooh Yes, it is a very deep black. ;-)